# Yii2: How do I get the database properties of model attributes?

Tags: model-view-controller, yii, attributes, yii2, schema

How do you get the database column properties of the attributes of a model? Like datatype, default value, size, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$customer_model->getTableSchema()` or `Customer::getTableSchema()`

Provides you with something like this:

```
yii\db\TableSchema#1 (
    [schemaName] => null
    [name] => 'customers'
    [fullName] => 'customers'
    [primaryKey] => [
        0 => 'customerID'
    ]
    [sequenceName] => ''
    [foreignKeys] => [
        0 => [
            0 => 'orders'
            'ord_customerID' => 'customerID'
        ]
    ]
    [columns] => [
        'customerID' => yii\db\ColumnSchema#2 (
            [name] => 'customerID'
            [allowNull] => false
            [type] => 'integer'
            [phpType] => 'integer'
            [dbType] => 'int(10) unsigned'
            [defaultValue] => null
            [enumValues] => null
            [size] => 10
            [precision] => 10
            [scale] => null
            [isPrimaryKey] => true
            [autoIncrement] => true
            [unsigned] => true
            [comment] => ''
        )
    ...
```